# I'm trying to call a method to check a value in my class but still keep getting wrong outputs

Tags: python, class, object, methods, default

I'm new at python.
I call a method to check a specific value in my class but still keep getting wrong outputs.
I want to change all the genders that are not like "F" or "M" to "F" by default.

```
class Customer:

    def __init__(self, name, last_name, address, phone, gender, id):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.address = address
        self.phone = phone
        self.gender = self.check_gender(gender)
        self.id = id

    def print_cus_info(self):
        return ("Name: {}, Last Name: {}, Address: {}, Phone: {}, Gender: {}, ID: {}".
              format(self.name, self.last_name, self.address, self.phone, self.gender, self.id))
    def get_cus_info(self):
        cus_list_value = [self.name, self.last_name, self.address, self.phone, self.gender]
        return ", ".join(cus_list_value)
    def check_gender(self, gender):
        if gender != "M" or gender != "F":
            self.gender = "F"
        return self.gender
```

Comment: You want `gender != 'M' and gender != 'F'`.

Comment: This sort of logic should probably happen in the constructor, and honestly, it should probably be a `ValueError` to provide a string that isn't understood.

Comment: Just a heads up since you're a new user. Asking beginner and homework questions in SO is acceptable, and you'll likely get an answer, but you're likely to find your question downvoted, which means that your question is not useful to most people in general. Note that if beginner and homework questions are all the questions that you ask on SO, and you ask a lot of them, you may encounter a ban on asking further questions.

Comment: Thnx I will pay attention for that.